# ESP32 serial communucation between 2 of them

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller, esp32, serial-communication

I'm trying to do a small project between which involves measuring temperature with an ESP32, send it through a serial connection to another ESP32, and make the latter write on the the Serial connection with my computer. I am using some LEDs for monitoring.

The code for the sender is:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Set Global variables

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// set the LCD number of columns and rows
#define LED1 32
#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 17
#define DHTPIN 33     // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

int lcdColumns = 16;
int lcdRows = 2;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, lcdColumns, lcdRows);  

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Serial Communication
HardwareSerial Sender(2); // use Sender

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Setup function
void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Sender.begin(19200,SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);
  lcd.init();
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.print("Finished loading");
  pinMode(LED1, OUTPUT);
  dht.begin();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Loop function
void loop() {
  float t1 = dht.readTemperature();
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  
  Sender.print(String(t1));
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Temp1(C): " + String(t1) + "\n");
  lcd.setCursor(0,1);
  lcd.print("Humid: " + String(h));
  //lcd.print("Temp2(C): " + String(t2) + "\n");

  digitalWrite(LED1, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(LED1, LOW);
  delay(200);
}
```

The code for the receiver is:

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Set Global variables

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// set the Serial Port Data
#define RXD2 16
#define TXD2 17
HardwareSerial Receiver(2); // use Receiver

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// set other relevant variables
#define LED 33
String message;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Setup function
void setup() {
  
  // Setup the Serial communication
  Receiver.begin(19200,SERIAL_8N1, RXD2, TXD2);

  // LED check
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(200);
  digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Loop function
void loop() {
  
  while(Receiver.available())
  {
    message = Receiver.read();
    Serial.println("Message received: " + message);
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
    delay(200);
  }
}
```

I checked that the sensor is correctly measuring and changing, but the receiver is not receiving correctly the information, or at least it isn't able to send it to the Serial connection.

Comment: I don't use the library, but wouldn't you need to swap `RXD2, TXD2` for `TXD2, RXD2` in either the `Sender.begin()` or `Receiver.begin()` for the different `HardwareSerial` instances?

Comment: @ DavidC.Rankin The RX and TX pins are defined by the board. When cconnecting both boards you just connect the Rx to the Tx of the other board and vice-versa.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: They're both `HardwareSerial` objects so they'll take the pins in the same order.  Now, the TXD2 pin of the first ESP32 had better be connected to the RXD2 pin of the second one.  And I guess the TXD2 pin of the second one is connected to the PC, not back to RXD2 of the first ESP32.

Comment: Or something.  There isn't enough code here to know if the second ESP32 is using two separate UART peripherals or split RX and TX from one peripheral.  The `Serial` object or namespace seems to be used as `Serial.println()` without ever being initialized.

Comment: I would try a `Serial.println()` in the second ESP32's code somewhere outside of the receive loop, to independently test the connection to the PC.  Also it isn't clear whether the LED is blinking, which would provide a means of testing the reception without relying on the PC.

Comment: @BenVoigt The TXD2 is connected to the RXD2 of the other one. All this is because the information between boards is done through the UART2 of the board, and the communication to the computer through the UART0. Is there anything wrong with that? The Serial doesn't need initialization, at least with the Arduino IDE as long as I know. And the LEDs are blinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By initializing the communication with the computer with another HardwareSerial instance instead of the default Serial instance the message was sent.

Comment: Good job sticking to it and solving the issue.